# Beginner here - RelativeLayout in Android Studio not working as expected

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I am simply trying to put two Edit Text views on the screen. One I want to alight with the left side, the other with the right side. However, in the Layout Editor, it shows my left text being aligned with the left side of the screen with a small buffer (as I would want), but my right text is all the way touching the right side of the screen.

Here's my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ballCounter"
        android:layout_width="104dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_ParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="223dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/strikeCounter"
        android:layout_width="104dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_ParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="223dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Sorry if the question is extremely basic, but I'm not quite sure how else to word it when googling. How can I get my right view (strikeCounter) to align the way that the left view (ballCounter) does?

Image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsi7r.png

Comment: Are you asking to have a buffer on the right side of strikeCounter editText? your marginRight is 0dp for that one. Change that (or use marginEnd like it will try to tell you)

Comment: @Tyler Sorry, meant to include a picture of the example. I've updated the post with a link to the screenshot - I was trying to get my strikeCounter to have some spacing between in and the right side of the screen, the same way that ballCounter does.

Comment: i am adding solution please try that.

Answer (score 0):

Add spacing to the right on the marginRight field. Currently marginRight is 0dp, so naturally there will be 0 pixels between the edge of the screen and the end of the text box.

```
android:layout_marginRight="41dp"
```

41 only because you have that for ballCounter

Comment: Not doubting you, but I did this and it's still staying on the right side of the screen. Am I missing anything?

Comment: I got it to work, I needed to add pixels to marginEnd for my strikeCounter (note that marginStart for ballCounter had a value). I'm more curious now as to why I had to add pixels to the "Start" and "End" of my views, rather than "Left" and "Right" which didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use this way......

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ballCounter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Left Side"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/strikeCounter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Right Side"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="number" />

</LinearLayout>
```

set strikeCounter text as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this...**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     tools:context=".MainActivity">

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/ballCounter"
         android:layout_width="104dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
         android:ems="10"
         android:inputType="number" />

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/strikeCounter"
         android:layout_width="104dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:layout_marginEnd="19dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
         android:ems="10"
         android:inputType="number" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check This

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ballCounter"
        android:layout_width="104dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/strikeCounter"
        android:layout_width="104dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

</RelativeLayout>
```